# Determine the following matrix if it's in REF, RREF or not in Echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix is in Row Echelon Form (REF) if it has the following applied:

1. Pivots go top left to bottom right
2. Zeros are below each pivot
3. Any row of all zeros must be at the bottom.

And a matrix is in Reduced Row Echelon Form(RREF) if it has the following applied:

1. REF
2. Pivots are 1
3. pivots are only non-zero entry in each column.

Examples:

1. $$\begin{bmatrix} 
   8 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 6 & -4 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$ **Not in echelon form**, because of REF #2, the number below the pivot is not a zero.
2. $$\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & -5 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 9 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$ **Not in echelon form**, because of REF #3 and also not in RREF because of RREF #3 that pivots are the only non-zero entry in each column.
3. $$\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 6 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$ **REF**
4. $$\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & -6 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$ **RREF**

Am I correct in identifying the matrices? If not, could you help me underdstand why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is all correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you!